# typescript parse CSV file

Tags: angular, csv, parsing, typescript, delimiter

I am using Angular and I need to parse a CSV file and write each field into database in TypeScript. In the file that we use there is a mixture of delimited and non-delimited fields (for that reason I want to use `"` as the delimiter).

One sample of my file is:

```
LastName,FirstName,Mobile,Email,"Job Title"
a,test,78787888,a@yahoo.com,Developer
gh,mary,"0506 444 435",mar@gmail.com,Developer
Zu,Jg,067889990,jg@yahoo.com,"Team Leader"
```

I found many samples for CSV parsing in JavaScript, none of them work for my data.

Comment: What exactly does not work for your data? What have you tried?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so any valid JavaScript is therefore valid TypeScript. You should post the relevant code and any error messages so we can see what the actual problem is.